# How to pass variables into a SQL string field?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I tried to pass a variable directly in one of my SQL string field but I didn't find the correct syntax.

I tried by doing " {variable} " or also " @variable " but when I give this to my software, it disps that like a string !

My function which is getting the SQL string (It's working)

```cs
public List<Dare> getDares()
        {
            if (myDataSet.Tables["TousLesGages"] != null)
            {
                myDataSet.Tables["TousLesGages"].Clear();
            }

            List<Dare> dares = new List<Dare>();

            connect();

            query = "SELECT * FROM Dare";
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = query;
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "TousLesGages");

            foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables["TousLesGages"].Rows)
            {
                Dare dare = new Dare((int)row.ItemArray[0], 
                                     row.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                                     category.getCategoryById((int)row.ItemArray[2]),
                                     type.getTypeById((int)row.ItemArray[3]),
                                     null);
                dares.Add(dare);
            }

            return dares;
        }
```

How I disp it :

```cs
gage = dare.getDares()[rndGage.Next(0, dare.getDares().Count)];
lblDare.Text = gage.text;
```

I expect the output of {drink} to be an integer understanding between 1 and 5 (I already created the Random object to permit it, its name is "drink" by the way)

[Server Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEwDr.png)

[Client Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK7TW.png)

Comment: I cant see anywhere that you are linking that text containing {drink} to the code you have provided. Is this supposed to be a paramaterised query? Bit hard to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It looks like you're storing and retrieving data that contains content placeholders. After retrieving the data, you need to interpret the placeholders before displaying the content in your application. The database won't do that. Find a library that does that or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way to do it without using a library. You can only use a string interpolation with strings and not variables, like :

```cs
string name = "John";
string result = $"{name}";
```

BUT ! Instead of that, I used the string.Format() function :

```cs
// gage.Text is a string containing "bla bla {0} bla"
// drink is an integer between 1 and 5

lblDare.Text = string.Format(gage.text, drink);
```

I hope it will help people ! :)

Comment: You're right, string interpolation is handled by the compiler, there's nothing magic in strings that handle this, nor with the code that handles databases.